# How to calculate the expectation E(max{K-X,0})

Tags: statistics

How to calculate E(max{K-X,0}), where X is a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and K is a constant.

There is hint on the book saying use (K-X) = (K - $\mu$) - (X-$\mu$). I'm not sure how to interprete this.

My own trial: 
I know max{K-X,0) = K-X if X < K else 0
So I tried the integration $\int_{-\infty}^{K} (K-X) f(x) dx$, where f(x) is the probability density function.
But I then got the term $-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi} \exp[-\frac{1}{2}u^2]$|_{-\infty}^{\frac{k-\mu}{\sigma}}. Should I evaluate $-\infty^2$ as positive infinity so it evaluates to 0 on exponential?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

max(K - X, 0) is a mixture distribution with a point mass p0 at 0 and a truncated normal distribution to the right of that, with mass 1 - p0, where p0 = p(X > K). The expected value of a mixture distribution is just the weighted sum of the expected values of the mixture components, with the weights being just the mixture proportions. So E(max(K - X, 0)) = (p0 times 0) + ((1 - p0) times E(truncated normal component)). I think you can figure out the truncated normal part.

By the way, you might get more interest in questions like this at math.stackexchange.com.